# Add corner ribbon to bootstrap site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I get this ribbon to be on of my bootstrap page as the top layer? Solid color and solid text.

html:

```
<div class="corner-ribbon bottom-left sticky orange">Hello</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* The ribbons */

.corner-ribbon{
  width: 200px;
  background: #e43;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* Custom styles */

.corner-ribbon.sticky{
  position: fixed;
}

.corner-ribbon.shadow{
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.corner-ribbon.bottom-left{
  top: auto;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: -50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}


/* Colors */

.corner-ribbon.white{background: #f0f0f0; color: #555;}
.corner-ribbon.black{background: #333;}
.corner-ribbon.grey{background: #999;}
.corner-ribbon.blue{background: #39d;}
.corner-ribbon.green{background: #2c7;}
.corner-ribbon.turquoise{background: #1b9;}
.corner-ribbon.purple{background: #95b;}
.corner-ribbon.red{background: #e43;}
.corner-ribbon.orange{background: #e82;}
.corner-ribbon.yellow{background: #ec0;}
```

As it is now the ribbon in on the same "level" as the background. Meaning that youtube iframe links etc. will go on the top of the ribbon.

I use this template:

https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/

If you would recommend me to use another code, please let me know.

Comment: Do you have this live somewhere, or can put drop this into a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is the `z-index` property.

```
.corner-ribbon{
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  background: #e43;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `z-index`:

```css
/* The ribbons */

.corner-ribbon{
  width: 200px;
  background: #e43;
  top: 25px;
  left: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* Pay attention! */
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
}

/* Custom styles */

.
corner-ribbon.sticky{
  position: fixed;
}

.corner-ribbon.shadow{
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.corner-ribbon.bottom-left{
  top: auto;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: -50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}


/* Colors */

.corner-ribbon.white{background: #f0f0f0; color: #555;}
.corner-ribbon.black{background: #333;}
.corner-ribbon.grey{background: #999;}
.corner-ribbon.blue{background: #39d;}
.corner-ribbon.green{background: #2c7;}
.corner-ribbon.turquoise{background: #1b9;}
.corner-ribbon.purple{background: #95b;}
.corner-ribbon.red{background: #e43;}
.corner-ribbon.orange{background: #e82;}
.corner-ribbon.yellow{background: #ec0;}

.annoying_block{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="corner-ribbon bottom-left sticky orange">Hello</div>
<div class="annoying_block">

</div>
```